# Basic HTML: External Stylesheet not linking

Tags: css, html

Just starting up a new HTML project and learning as I go, but I can't seem to figure out why my code isn't linking up. I'm trying to make my picture 100% width of the screen, and I'm realizing that my code just isn't lining up.

Any advice please?

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>liz project</title>

<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen">


</head>
<body>

<h1>my first project</h1>
<p> welcome to the best site on the planet woohoo <br>
<img class="bg" src="http://blissmakedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/livingroom1.jpg"> </p>
```

This is my CSS:

```
h1 {font-family: arial; color: red }

.bg {width: 100%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto }
```

Super basic, just started. Thanks so much!

Comment: is file `stylesheet.css` in same directory?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here. Use your browser's developer tools. Look in the Net tab. Are all the files loading successfully? Are you getting `200 OK` status codes in the responses?

Comment: I would remove the media="screen" if you are not using a different stylesheet for print. otherwise your page will look horrible when printed. Also, is the font displaying red? Or does this not work also?

Comment: Nothing that I've specified in the CSS is displaying at all. They're both saved in my desktop, so should I specify that path?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to learn about using the file path.

[quick reminder about file path](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

1. Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
2. Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
3. Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
   there (and so on...)
4. To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
   moving forward

---

So, make sure your file path is in correct direction.

Comment: they are both saved in my desktop, but i tried explicitly writing the path and it still won't seem to link

Answer (score 0):

You've got pretty much everything right there, like others have said it's going to be something like the CSS file just can't be found. This could be maybe because it's inside a folder and not at the root of your HTML file?

In this case, you would just need to change the link to your CSS file to reflect the folder it's in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/[folder name]/stylesheet.css">
```

Note I have removed `media="screen"` as generally, for a basic tutorial, you wouldn't really need it so I wouldn't worry about it.

Also note at the start I've used lowecase for `link`. I don't know if this was causing your issues, but it's worth trying to stick with lowercase for everything, unless you need uppercase.

And one last point, I'm not sure you really need `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` as your image is classed to take up 100% of the width, so there won't be any margins available. You could remove those declarations in your CSS file if you wish.

Are you able to show us a brief example of how your files and folders are layed out?

Comment: Just changed LINK to lowercase and nothing seemed to work. Both of these are written in textedit and saved in my desktop. Still can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Hmm when you're using TextEdit, you're using it in plain text mode? and saving the files as .HTML? Do they render in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lee and C-link Nepal. It's probably a path error, so make sure your stylesheet is in the same directory as your html page. In the future, you can inspect a page with issues on your browser by right clicking on an element and selecting "Inspect Element" or something similar. In the inspection pane you can check if any files weren't found, which may point you in the right direction.